# Is it possible to write MyGeneration Templates in F# and how?

Tags: c#, f#, mygeneration

I want to write a MyGeneration Template File in F#. I know you can target various languages etc VB.NET and C# however for my own selfish benefit I would like to write it in F#.

Anyone one if and how this is possible?

Comment: you mean F# as GUI_LANGUAGE, or OUTPUT_LANGUAGE?

Comment: not really an answer but maybe you could try hacking together some example template file in C# and some of us might be able to help you to translate it to F# and then you could try it to see if it works.

Comment: Im looking to use F# as the Input language and then generate C# code ... well now that I think about it. Perhaps I should be generating F# code. Im not fully up to speed with F# and wanted to use it as an opertunity to get stuck in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio you can use T4 templating to generate any type of output using a psudo "asp classic" style syntax, where you intermix your code (F#) and the "output."

Heres a good place to get started: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nate, not the answer I was looking for but this solves the problem! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure writing a template in F# would be the best move. Although it could be done by referencing a Class Library (At least in [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com)). This way you could move all of your F# logic and processing code into a Visual Studio Class Library and still use it inside of the template.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))